# How to fix cannot deserialize JSON, confused with the key "1" , "2"

Tags: c#, json.net

I am confuse with the numbered(the key) newslist (array)

The json string is valid, in nodeJS it managed to output the values that i need.

**JSON STRING as is**

```
{
  "newsalert": [{
    "newslist": {
      "1": {
        "newsid": "4321",
        "headline": "Great White Shark Found",
        "newscode": "GWS",
        "newstime": "10:04:32"
      },
      "2": {
        "newsid": "8031",
        "headline": "Polar Bear Escaped",
        "newscode": "PBE",
        "newstime": "09:28:03"
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

**C# Code**

```
class MainNews {
    public Dictionary<string, newslist[]> newsalert { get; set; }
}

class newslist {
    public int newsid { get; set; }
    public string headline{ get; set; }
    public string newscode { get; set; }
    public string newstime { get; set; }
}

static void ShowObject(MainNews obj) {
    foreach (var item in obj.news.Values.ElementAt(0)) {
        MessageBox.Show(item.headline);
    }
}

private void BtnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var xnews = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MainNews>(jsonstring);
    ShowObject(xnews);
}
```

**Error**

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the
>   current JSON array because the type requires a JSON object

Comment: Your C# class doesn't match your Json `MainNews` should have a List of `NewsAlert` and object with a newslist property that is a `Dictionary<int, newslist>`. You are missing one object betwwen the root and the dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a step betwwen your root and the Dictionary.
`newsalert` is a collection on a object with a property name `newslist`.
That this is your dictionary.

```
public class MainNews
{
    public List<NewAlert> newsalert { get; set; }
}

public class NewAlert
{
    public Dictionary<int, NewItem> newslist { get; set; }
}

public class NewItem
{
    public string newsid { get; set; }
    public string headline { get; set; }
    public string newscode { get; set; }
    public string newstime { get; set; }
}
```

You can simply :

```
string input = @"{
  ""newsalert"": [{
    ""newslist"": {
      ""1"": {
        ""newsid"": ""4321"",
        ""headline"": ""Great White Shark Found"",
        ""newscode"": ""GWS"",
        ""newstime"": ""10:04:32""
      },
      ""2"": {
        ""newsid"": ""8031"",
        ""headline"": ""Polar Bear Escaped"",
        ""newscode"": ""PBE"",
        ""newstime"": ""09:28:03""
      }
    }
  }]
}";


var result =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MainNews>(input);       
result.newsalert.SelectMany(x=> x.newslist.Values).Dump();
```

Live Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ar5ocP

Comment: It worked :)  I need to practice more. Thank you for your help  @xdtTransform